# how to apply an odata FilterClause on an IEnumerable/IQueryable collection

Tags: c#, filter, odata

i'm implementing some functions for our odata v4 service. 
we want to support the filter query option for all functions, just like entity collection.

Say we have a SearchProducts function that accept a ProductType parameter, and returns all products that belong to the specific ProductType.

now the question is, i failed to find any odata built-in method that supports this need. the only way i can figure out is manually parsing the FilterClause, and then apply it on the result returned from function.

check this sample code:

```
IQueryable<Product> collection = _service.SearchProducts(ProductType.Phone); 
var parser = new ODataUriParser(model, new Uri("SearchProducts(ProductType='Phone')?$filter=Name eq 'IPhone'", UriKind.Relative));
var filter = parser.ParseFilter();
// TODO: apply filter on collection, to filter all iphones. get the results same as the following code 
// TODO: collection = collection.Where(p=>p.Name == "IPhone");
```

the collection will be all Phone products. after add the $filter string, it should returns all IPhone products.

I can parse the FilterClause to a lambda expression and then apply it on collection to return the correct results. but considering on the complexity of the $filter, the parser may be very complex and will cost much time.

anyone has a quick solution on this? thank you

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @PavelJedlicka i did not find a easy way, and ended up manually parsing the filter

Answer (score 1):

The real question is: How to use OData query language for filtering without the whole odata's asp infrastructure?
It can be done by extracting $filter and applyning it to your IQuerable db Context.
Same can be done with searching. This way we have more flexibility, yet reuse the OData sql generation code and parsing logic.

First, register in DI this `model`, so you can inject it anywhere:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
```

Then, in your controller accept filter parameters as a string parameter:

```
IActionResult Get(string filterParam) 
{
   // test query
   filterParam = "(MyCount ne 10) and (EnumField in ('1', '2')) and (Address/Id eq 1)";
```

Later build something like this. You can place here other stuff, like $search, $top, $count:

```
Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"$filter", filterParam },
};
```

Parse the query:

```
IEdmType type = model.FindDeclaredType("MyEntities.Order");
IEdmNavigationSource source = model.FindDeclaredEntitySet("Orders");
ODataQueryOptionParser parser = new ODataQueryOptionParser(model, type, source, options);
```

Apply it to your DB Context's Set. IQuerable will contain the SQL generated to narrow how your results.

```
var context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(Order), null);
var opts = new ODataQueryOptions<Order>(context, this.Request);
FilterQueryOption filterQuery = new FilterQueryOption(" ", context, parser);
 
var iQuerableResult = filterQuery.ApplyTo(_dbSet_dbContext, new ODataQuerySettings { });
```

Please remember, that it's a raw PoC code. Not something that is production ready.